# Как положить первое слово в отдельный массив?

Tags: c, массивы, строки, циклы

У меня есть программа, которая считывает ввод строки и кладёт её в отдельный массив *finalArr*.
**Все слова в этом массиве имеют длину 3**.
Мне нужно взять оттуда первое слово и положить его в отдельный массив *distArr*. Но при запуске, ничего не выводится.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(void)
{
    char finalArr[100];
    char src;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    // заполняем массив
    while ((src = getchar()) != '\n' && i < 99)
    {
        finalArr[i] = src;
        i++;
    }
    finalArr[i] = '\0';
    printf("Result is: %s\n", finalArr); // выводим введённую строку

    // Непосредственно код, который должен записывать первое слово в отдельный массив
    char distArr[100];
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < strlen(finalArr); j++)
    {
        finalArr[j] = distArr[j];
        if (finalArr[j] == ' ')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    distArr[j] = '\0';
    printf("Dist array is %s", distArr);
}
```

**Например, массив *finalArr* - "qwe qwe qwe", массив *distArr* - "qwe"**

Comment: в `finalArr[j] = distArr[j];` перепутали что куда записывать. `distArr[j] = finalArr[j] ;`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Спасибо большое!